# Order mail confirmation generates DOMXPath::query() error

Tags: magento2, checkout, error, order-email

on order place the email contains the following error and does not display properly

```
CSS Inline Error: Warning: DOMXPath::query(): Invalid expression in .../vendor/pelago/emogrifier/Classes/Emogrifier.php on line 269
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Any update on this issue

Comment: i also facing same issue :)

Answer (score 5):

This may be a bug of [Emogrifier module](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4737).

Put this in the `require-dev` part of `composer.json`:

```
"pelago/emogrifier": "1.0.0 as 0.1.1"
```

Or prefer the development version:

```
"pelago/emogrifier": "dev-master as 0.1.1"
```

**There is a notice:** seem that this issue also occurs when processing static content deploy.

**UPDATE:**

We should take a look:

*vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/email.less*

```
@import 'source/lib/_lib.less'; // Global lib
@import 'source/lib/variables/_email.less'; // Global email variables
@import 'source/_theme.less'; // Global variables override
@import 'source/_variables.less'; // Local theme variables
@import 'source/_email-variables.less'; // Theme variables for emails
```

**Magento email will import some less files**. So, if we added **some unsupported selectors** to these files, that may cause this issue.

*vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/source/_email-base.less*

```
Unsupported selectors (examples in parenthesis):
      * first-child (div:first-child)
      * last-child (div:last-child)
      * nth-child (div:nth-child(3n+1))
      * universal (*)
      * pseudo (a:hover, a:active, a:focus, span:before, span:after, etc)
```

For example, in our custom theme, we add some unsupported selectors:

*app/design/frontend/VendorTheme/default/web/css/source/_theme.less*

```
...
#customer-service-menu li.item:nth-child(2) {position: absolute;}
...
```

This issue will occurs again.

**SOLUTION:**

**We should create a new folder which contains the stand less files for our email styles**. And, these files are only for email.

*app/design/frontend/VendorTheme/default/web/css/email.less*

```
@import 'source/lib/email/stand/_lib.less'; // Global lib
@import 'source/lib/email/stand/variables/_email.less'; // Global email variables
```

Comment: [UnexpectedValueException]                                                      
  Could not parse version constraint as 0.1.1: Invalid version string "as 0.1.1"

Answer (score 2):

*I just recently came from similar problem. I hope these changes may help you.*

**found a solution for Magento 2**

**created the files**

> /web/css/email.less

and

> /web/css/email-inline.less

in my custom theme and added the content from

> /vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/email.less

and

> /vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/email-inline.css
>   respectively

**Please Note below**

**but each with the line "@import 'source/_theme.less';" commented out (or removed)**

Comment: By doing this you are separating theme css from email css  right?

Comment: By doing this you are separating theme css from email css right?  ==> yes, I hope  this solution helpful for you

Answer (score 1):

Using Magento 2.2.2 and experiencing the same error and fixed it this way:

`"pelago/emogrifier": "2.0.0 as 1.2.0"` as requirement in composer.json
`composer update pelago/emogifier && magento setup:upgrade`

Answer (score -1):

Now i got solution 
 
/var/www/html/vendor/pelago/emogrifier/Classes/Emogrifier.php

 Line 595,  find and replace below function

```
private function splitCssAndMediaQuery($css)
    {
        $media = '';

        $css = preg_replace_callback(
            '#@media\\s+(?:only\\s)?(?:[\\s{\\(]|screen|all)\\s?[^{]+{.*}\\s*}\\s*#misU',
            function ($matches) use (&$media) {
                $media .= $matches[0];
            },
            $css
        );

        // filter the CSS
        $search = array(
            // get rid of css comment code
            '/\\/\\*.*\\*\\//sU',
            // strip out any import directives
            '/^\\s*@import\\s[^;]+;/misU',
            // strip remains media enclosures
            '/^\\s*@media\\s[^{]+{(.*)}\\s*}\\s/misU',          
        );

        $replace = array(
            '',
            '',
            '',         
        );
```

replace

```
private function splitCssAndMediaQuery($css)
    {
        $media = '';

        $css = preg_replace_callback(
            '#@media\\s+(?:only\\s)?(?:[\\s{\\(]|screen|all)\\s?[^{]+{.*}\\s*}\\s*#misU',
            function ($matches) use (&$media) {
                $media .= $matches[0];
            },
            $css
        );

        // filter the CSS
        $search = array(
            // get rid of css comment code
            '/\\/\\*.*\\*\\//sU',
            // strip out any import directives
            '/^\\s*@import\\s[^;]+;/misU',
            // strip remains media enclosures
            '/^\\s*@media\\s[^{]+{(.*)}\\s*}\\s/misU',
            '/^\\s*@-?[A-Za-z-]+\\s[^{]+{(.*)}\\s*}\\s/misU',
        );

        $replace = array(
            '',
            '',
            '',
            '',
        );
```

Comment: it is not working

Comment: editing in files not a solution so please removed your ans from here