# CSS error in email template in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, email-templates

All the emails received have the following error

```
CSS inlining error: Warning: DOMXPath::query(): Invalid expression in /home/73299-56608.cloudwaysapps.com/qamfwwvwxj/public_html/vendor/pelago/emogrifier/Classes/Emogrifier.php on line 269
```

How can i resolve this error.

Check the attached image

[image]

Comment: How about your issue?

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh, Well I solved it. by removing all unsupported css.

Comment: from where you remove the css which is unsupported?

Comment: @HafizArslan  from the CSS that is included in email template, I have written some CSS(don't remember now the CSS) in `app/design/frontend/Magento/luma/web/css/source/_email-extend.less`  which was causing the issue, there are few other LESS files from which email CSS is generated you have to check them all

Comment: what is your php version?

Comment: I think the project was in Magento 2.0.x and PHP 7.0.X, don't remember exactly. It is a very old project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Magento email will import some default less files. So, if we added some **unsupported selectors to these files**, that may cause this issue: [Order mail confirmation generates DOMXPath::query() error](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/116952/order-mail-confirmation-generates-domxpathquery-error)

Answer (score 0):

The .less files are processed to produce inline CSS for emails. For some less selectors, the parsing fails due to special characters. Here is a solution which may work for you http://awebtech.blogspot.in/2016/10/css-inline-error-warning-domxpathquery.html