# Magento 2 CSS inlining error

Tags: magento2, email, php-7.3

Getting following error in magento 2 email.

```
CSS inlining error: Warning: DOMXPath::query(): Invalid expression in /home/patios/public_html/vendor/pelago/emogrifier/Classes/Emogrifier.php on line 294
```

I have already tried to update pelado vendor. But still getting error.

```
"pelago/emogrifier": "1.0.0 as 0.1.1"
```

My magento version is 2.2.1

**Update**

Before upgrading pelago to to 1.0.0, error was like following...

```
Warning: DOMXPath::query(): Invalid expression in /home/public_html/vendor/pelago/emogrifier/Classes/Emogrifier.php on line 269

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/public_html/vendor/pelago/emogrifier/Classes/Emogrifier.php on line 272
```

Comment: what is your php version ?

Comment: just downgrade the php version 7.3 to 7.2 every thing is working fine

Answer (score 0):

Magento email will import some default less files.

So, if we added some unsupported selectors to these files, that may cause this issue: [Order mail confirmation generates DOMXPath::query() error](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/116952/order-mail-confirmation-generates-domxpathquery-error)

Reference [CSS error in email template in magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/140158/css-error-in-email-template-in-magento-2)

Answer (score 0):

This may be a bug of [Emogrifier module](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4737).

Put this in the `require-dev` part of `composer.json`:

```
"pelago/emogrifier": "1.0.0 as 0.1.1"
```

Or prefer the development version:

```
"pelago/emogrifier": "dev-master as 0.1.1"
```

**There is a notice:** seem that this issue also occurs when processing static content deploy.

**UPDATE:**

We should take a look:

*vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/email.less*

```
@import 'source/lib/_lib.less'; // Global lib
@import 'source/lib/variables/_email.less'; // Global email variables
@import 'source/_theme.less'; // Global variables override
@import 'source/_variables.less'; // Local theme variables
@import 'source/_email-variables.less'; // Theme variables for emails
```

**Magento email will import some less files**. So, if we added **some unsupported selectors** to these files, that may cause this issue.

*vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/source/_email-base.less*

```
Unsupported selectors (examples in parenthesis):
      * first-child (div:first-child)
      * last-child (div:last-child)
      * nth-child (div:nth-child(3n+1))
      * universal (*)
      * pseudo (a:hover, a:active, a:focus, span:before, span:after, etc)
```

For example, in our custom theme, we add some unsupported selectors:

*app/design/frontend/VendorTheme/default/web/css/source/_theme.less*

```
...
#customer-service-menu li.item:nth-child(2) {position: absolute;}
...
```

This issue will occurs again.

**SOLUTION:**

**We should create a new folder which contains the stand less files for our email styles**. And, these files are only for email.

*app/design/frontend/VendorTheme/default/web/css/email.less*

```
@import 'source/lib/email/stand/_lib.less'; // Global lib
@import 'source/lib/email/stand/variables/_email.less'; // Global email variables
```