# Getting Error in email notification on magento 2.2.6

Tags: magento2, server-setup, magento2.2.6

I am facing this error on my mail in magento 2 (Currently using version 2.2.6)

On email notification I am getting this error (screenshot). Either it will be a newsletter email or success order email or anything else.

Screenshot Url:

https://prnt.sc/l2ek3a

Comment: I think there is problem in your email template css as shown in error . can you paste here any of your template ?

Comment: you should check this too if it helps - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/116952/order-mail-confirmation-generates-domxpathquery-error

Comment: Hello, Here is the code of email template that i am using:


 {{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}}
<div style="padding:20px; background-color:#fff;">
<p>{{trans "Thank you for subscribing to our newsletter."}}</p>
</div>
{{template config_path="design/email/footer_template"}}

Comment: did you check above link ? have it not worked ?

Comment: Great to hear that !!!